# How to install apc on Centos 5.6

Tags: installation, centos, apc

How to install apc on centos 5.6.

I have already installed the latest lamp package, but could not find how to install apc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can install that by using `pecl install apc`

http://2bits.com/articles/installing-php-apc-gnulinux-centos-5.html This article is the complete guide...I installed mine using it as well.